# Is it possible to make piston flying machine that bounces?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I allways dreamt about making a piston device that can push itself. Now, with the addition of slime blocks, [my dreams came true](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-tqLTsCnRc).

The only flaw of these machines is that they work until they hit some wall, then they get stuck. I was wondering if there's a possibility to make a design that changes shape by hitting the wall and continues in the opposite direction...

Is there anything in minecraft that would make such design impossible?

Comment: Why not ask [Sethbling](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8aG3LDTDwNR1UQhSn9uVrw)! He might be able to help you.

Comment: When you do a way to build it, put a link here, that sounds awesome :)

Comment: This sounds like it would be possible, but it would need pistons that could go in all 4 directions. This seems like it would use a lot of space to build a machine capable of that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I know that this is the smallest flying machine:
[image: Smallest flying machine]

And to start it you just give power to the sticky piston. But you could probably do something like add another piston facing the opposite direction at the end of the flying machine and have a redstone block 2 blocks away from that piston so that when the machine hits a wall, the machine would compact up allowing the redstone block to go 1 block away from the piston, BUD powering it and starting up the machine in the opposite direction. That's just my guess, but if you're looking for a 4-way flying machine, then there is lots of videos of that on youtube. If this is a bad answer, please don't be mean because I am quite new to stack exchange.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange then. I wasn't even remotely looking for 4-way flying machine. I was looking for machine that reconstructs itself upon hitting a wall so that it goes in the opposite direction. Think about automatic sugar cane harvester.